# How to change the highlight color in autocomplete box in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, gtk

I can't find a way to change the color of the highlighted selection in the autocomplete box in Eclipse.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot white text on light gray background is not very readable.

---

Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity and Eclipse Classic

---

**Update:** This is system dependent, indeed. Changing the Ubuntu theme changes this color. There are settings about this in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/`, but I can't figure out which one. The background is a gradient, so picking the color and grepping for it does not work.

Comment: @Polynomial: Question updated.

Comment: There is a duplicate on ask ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/62421/eclipse-content-assist-popup-is-unreadable-on-ambiance-radiance-theme

Comment: possible duplicate of [The selected entry in Eclipse content assist is unreadable because of colours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424800/the-selected-entry-in-eclipse-content-assist-is-unreadable-because-of-colours)

Comment: would be great to know how it is done in windows too - i am suffering hard here ...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

it must be a system setting, try the Ubuntu control center (system settings) / appearance / customize. Click all the tabs and see which color matches the color in eclipse.

**Update:**
I just realized that in ubuntu 11.04 for some weird reason the possibility to customize the colors was removed, you need to change the config files

```
sudo vim /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

in my version line 94 is

```
base[ACTIVE]      = shade (0.97, @bg_color)
```

which you need to change as you wish, e.g.:

```
base[ACTIVE]      = shade (0.50, @bg_color)
```

then you go to System settings / appearance, change the theme to something then change back to Ambience and voila, things are changed. I just can't imagine why there is no UI for changing this.

Update 2: this is slightly similar to what the other commenter suggested, just in a different file. I guess the difference is that will affect the system globally

**UPDATE 2 :**

in ubuntu 11.10 there is still no GUI to change the theme colors, but they also changed the file structure so exectute the following command (same as above)

```
sudo vim /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

and search for this section that controls tooltip colors :

```
style "tooltips" {
    bg[NORMAL]        = @tooltip_bg_color
    fg[NORMAL]        = @tooltip_fg_color
}
```

and alter is as you wish e.g.:

```
    bg[NORMAL]        = "#000000"
    fg[NORMAL]        = "#FFFFFF"
```

**UPDATE 3 :**

In ubuntu 12.04 you need to do both changes described in update 1 and update 2

Comment: Thanks for this. You may want to note that the use of sudo is required to edit the file.

Comment: The GUI for adjusting colors is called `gnome-color-chooser` which, unfortunately, is not installed by default.

Comment: any suggestion for Windows user.?

Answer (score 40):

This problem can also be fixed from within Eclipse, as is described in the blog post [Fix Eclipse colours in ubuntu 12.04](http://michael-weimann.eu/fix-eclipse-colours-in-ubuntu-12-04/).

1. Go into the Preferences (Window -> Preferences)
2. Choose General -> Appearance from the left menu
3. Uncheck the checkbox ***Use mixed fonts and colours for labels***

**Before**

[image: the bad colored code completion window in eclipse]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Too bad: the above setting disappeared in Eclipse 4.2; see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378959

Comment: Worked for me for Ubuntu 12.04 + Eclipse Juno

Comment: Many, many thanks for this solution. It works also for Windows.

Answer (score 8):

for Ubuntu 12.04, simply edit the file `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`
search for

```
  base[ACTIVE]      = shade (0.94, @bg_color)
```

change the shade percentage from 0.94 to whatever visible like 0.54

```
  base[ACTIVE]      = shade (0.54, @bg_color)
```

then it works.

Comment: Thank you!  I have been looking for a solution to this for 30 minutes, and this is the first one that actually worked.

Comment: Works nicely for the default Ambiance theme indeed. Of course, the reference to Ambiance in the path name should have told me that this has no effect on Radiance, which has its own folder in `/usr/share/themes`. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**How to change it for all Ubuntu themes**

On Ubuntu you can add a fix to the Appearance theme:

- Open a terminal ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> )
- Create a new file with: `gedit ~/.gtkrc-2.0`
- In that file add these lines:

  ```
  style "eclipse_fix" 
  { 
  base[ACTIVE] = shade(0.7, "#F2F1F0") 
  }

  class "GtkTreeView" style "eclipse_fix"
  ```
- Save file
- In System Settings > Appearance, switch to an other theme and then switch back to the theme you had. This is done to "refresh" the current theme with the fix. (Alternatively, log out and log in again.)
- Test in Eclipse, hopefully your content assist will be readable ;)

Comment: Here is the setup on how to **load settings only for Eclipse** and also **customize the tooltips**: http://askubuntu.com/a/131348/18533

Comment: I compiled an [article](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120728/how-to-fix-eclipse-colors-for-autocompletion-and-tooltips/) which summarizes the topic.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use the command prompt at all.

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Basic -> Content Assist background color / Content Assist foreground color

Everything is customizable via the GUI.

[image: how to change the content assist color in eclipse]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can update the variables at the top of the gtkrc file. For your particular problem it would be selected_fg_color, not tooltip_fg_color, for example, change it from white to black(#000000). Here are my settings:

```
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\n
selected_bg_color:#f07746\nselected_fg_color:#000000\n
text_color:#3C3C3C\nbg_color:#F2F1F0\ntooltip_bg_color:#FFFFFF\nlink_color:#DD4814"
```

Comment: Tooltip Color is another topic. This is not working for me. Instead Just put this into the ~/.gtkrc-2.0 if you don't want to change system theme files: `style "eclipse-fix" {
 bg[NORMAL]        = "#cccccc"
 fg[NORMAL]        = "#000000"
 bg[SELECTED]      = "#cccccc"
}

widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "eclipse-fix"
`

Answer (score 0):

This may looks easy seems. That is change the  color theme of eclipse. 
Windows-> Preference -> Appearance -> Color theme.

Answer (score 0):

This topic always troubles me whenever I start working on a new PC or laptop.

Today, the exact same thing happened again, and I had to go through all the configurations once more to find the solution.

So I'm pasting the solution bellow:

### Setup:

1. STM32CubeIDE [v1.14.1] (tested also in previous versions)
2. DevStyle theme addon (darkest dark theme).

### Fix to the issue:

1. Windows >> Preferences >> C/C++ >> Editor
2. Inside editor's menu configurations to change:

- Completion proposal background
- Completion proposal foreground

[Screenshot that shows the solution to this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMEML.png)

I hope this helps others save time by not having to search for the solution again.