# Is there a way to change the colour of links on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I'm using Eclipse with the MoonRise theme installed on a Mac running OS X Yosemite, but I'm experiencing an issue which is that the background panel of Eclipse popups are dark grey and the colour of links is dark blue, making it difficult to see linked text against the background. As an example:

[image]

Is there a way I can change the colour of links to something brighter? I've tried Googling this problem and playing about with the Eclipse appearance preferences and so far nothing has helped. Is it the case that the link colour is hardcoded for Macs and I'm stuck with that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8012176/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM that question has solutions for Ubuntu, but what about Mac?  Is there at least a way to make the background box of the popup lighter?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I saw to get around this was to go to Eclipse > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Content Assist. From there I changed the Content assist background and foreground colors to light grey.