# Eclipse: How to change the highlight color of the selected item of input popup

Tags: java, eclipse

The first item "System-java.lang" is currently selected. But the color is not very obvious. How to change the color? OS is windows.

[image: Eclipse input hint]

Comment: Are you talking the editor or popup menu?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @Sundararaj Govindasamy Yeah. It's Windows.

Comment: @Jason Just the background color of selected item("System-java.lang" in the example).

Comment: Can you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28724598/1401019

Comment: @Sundararaj Govindasamy Can I just change the background color of the selected item(so it's easy to find which item is selected)?In the picture above, it's the background color of "System-java.lang",  not the whole popup. Maybe eclipse doesn't have this function.

Comment: Did you try foreground color as well? As goal is to make that 'highlighted text' different from non-selected items, I hope certain combination of background + foreground color would help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the color From: `Windows->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations`

Comment: Did I understand your need wrong, Just tell me what you need

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012176/how-to-change-the-highlight-color-in-autocomplete-box-in-eclipse) This is another color scheme. But it's on ubuntu. How to do it on Windows?

Comment: I never try this before, But you can find file specify in the link /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc and change the color

Comment: I try this because I want to easily distinguish which item is currently selected from other items. The color is not very obvious. It's on Windows, not Linux.