# Eclipse color helper background

Tags: eclipse, background-color

I have eclipse with modificate theme.

And when I use code helper (ctrl+spacebar), I don't see select line. Any idea, how to change background of select item or change color background helper?

[Picture of my select item....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTMgH.png)

Comment: Is this Eclipse 2018-09 or an outdated version? Which programming language is this about? C/C++?

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012176/how-to-change-the-highlight-color-in-autocomplete-box-in-eclipse

Comment: I have Windows 10; Eclipse IDE for C/C++, version 4.8.0

Comment: And I try change: Preferences -> General -> Appearance

Here I select:
Basic -> Content Assist background color to gray

And it isn't working.