# Eclipse Intellisense is unreadable in Windows 8

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense

I am using Eclipse on Windows 8 x64. The problem I have is that the Eclipse IntelliSense pop-up (not sure what its actual name is) is unreadable:

[image]

This is because the background is cream and the foreground is white. I have only managed to find solutions for Ubuntu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424800/the-selected-entry-in-eclipse-content-assist-is-unreadable-because-of-colours) but nothing for Windows.

How can I change either the background or the foreground color of the Eclipse IntelliSense pop-up to make it readable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The text in white are actually links, so I suspect that it's using the Windows default color for hyperlinks. I don't have use Windows so I can't tell you exactly where to change that, but I'd look at the standard Windows color/font settings and/or Internet Explorer settings.