# How change text color of debug window in eclipse (Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse

I tried to change color in `Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts` but I can't find proper field.

In Debug mode in Eclipse, when mouse is over object then new window appears. I have black background and gray text so it is very illegible. The picture below shows that window:
[image]

How to change that color?

Comment: check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45001/how-to-fix-black-tooltips-in-eclipse) [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250905/eclipse-the-color-used-for-text-in-a-content-assist-popup) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424800/the-selected-entry-in-eclipse-content-assist-is-unreadable-because-of-colours)