# DBeaver Content Assist colors

Tags: eclipse, dbeaver, aero

I am having difficulty getting the Content assist colors right.  With auto-completion, the first suggestion is always light color on light color. Here is what it looked like originally (Dracula Theme):

[image: DBeaver Screenshot]

Changing the values of Content Assist Background/Foreground colors did not have any affect on the top suggestion.  Here is a screenshot from after swapping the Content Assist Foreground and Background colors (Darkest Dark theme):

[image: DBeaver Darkest Dark]

I have tried swapping every other practical color setting in `Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts` with no luck.  The color scheme in the first image above is the popular Dracula theme that I manually set up setting by setting.  Thinking I screwed something up in there, I scrapped all that work and switched to the Eclipse DevStyle theme Darkest Dark.  Here, I was met with the same issue.  After this, I switched everything to default settings where the color scheme is black font on white background.  Everything is readable.  Switching back to the Darkest Dark, the issue remains.

I have found similar questions regarding this, but their solutions are mostly for Linux (GTK specifically).  This machine I am using is on Windows 7.  I also have a laptop that runs DBeaver on Arch Linux and does not suffer from this problem.  It seems this issue may be system dependent.  I found [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424800/the-selected-entry-in-eclipse-content-assist-is-unreadable-because-of-colours/13542749#13542749) that suggested changing the message box settings for Windows may fix this, but my message box settings are currently black text on white background.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Jason, do you know what editor you're using? If you right click and choose "open with" you'll see an editor currently selected. We tried both the default SQL editor and the DBeaver SQL editor but couldn't see this coloring issue. On the DevStyle page, have you tried using the "Force Colors" checkbox and ensuring the "allow oomph" checkbox is unchecked as you switch through a few themes?

Comment: @BrianFernandes Thanks for the response.  I did try the "Force Colors" option.  I will need to look tomorrow for the "allow oomph" option.  I can say that this issue started before I installed devstyle... I don't know if that is any help.  Installing devstyle was my attempt at a remedy.

Comment: @BrianFernandes I am actually using the standalone DBeaver client `Version 7.0.0.202003021717`.  So I think I only have 1 editor.  I couldn't find that "allow oomph" option.

Comment: Jason, could you try with a brand new dummy workspace to see if the problem occurs there too? That would help figure out if workspace settings are affecting this, or they're coming from elsewhere. Oomph settings (which will affect even new worksapces) can be found in the .eclipse folder in your home directory (directories named *oomph*). You could temporarily move these directories elsewhere to prevent them from interfering as well.

Comment: Hello! Can you let me know which Windows theme you have in your system? We know some system-level themes cause issues like this, for example, windows Classic.

Comment: @AaronIsaacLaraOtero Dude you nailed it.  I am using Windows 7 with Windows Classic theme.  I switched to Windows 7 Basic theme, and I could see the text.  Kind of sucks that I have to ditch my Windows XP style theme, but it is worth it here.  If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Awesome! Making it an answer then so others find it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the SWT widgets relay on the OS level theme. For example, it's known that using the Windows Classic theme at the OS level can cause oddities like this one. So just switching to a different theme can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have found the solution, just in case anyone is still searching...
we can change the color of "content assist", you can find in "Colors and fonts".

[click here to see the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVTfq.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).